# Create array with numeric data and characters

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I would like to know how I can create an array with two dimensions, the first being a numeric matrix and the second a character matrix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An array cant have multiple datatypes. What you are looking for is the `dataframe`.
For example, you can create a dataframe with a numeric and a character column like this:

```
df <- data.frame(numericColumn=1:26,characterColumn=LETTERS)
```

To access these columns, you can use square brackets or the names. For more details, just read the documentation of `dataframe` or search for some examples.

If you really want to store matrices of different types in one object, you can use a `list`, for example like

```
matrixList <- list(numericMatrix=someNumericMatrix,characterMatrix=someCharacterMatrix)
```